# Can't change posts per page in WordPress Post Type Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "Events". The post displays fine, except that the WP Query loop only displays one post instead of all of them. Here is the complete code from my functions.php file for Events:

```
    function min_get_events ( $echo = true ) {
     $events = new WP_query(array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'min_event-start',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key'     => 'min_event-start',
        'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '>',
    )
));

$i = 0;
$n = 1;

if ( $events->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $events->have_posts() ):
        global $post;
        $events->the_post();

        $open_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-start', true);
        $close_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-end', true);
        $start = strtotime($open_date);
        $end = strtotime($close_date);
        if ($start==$end || $start > $end) {
            $date_string = date('F j, Y', $start);
        }
        else {
            $date_string = date('F j, Y', $start) .' &ndash; '. date('F j, Y', $end);
        }
        //$description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-description', true);
        $location = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-location', true);
        $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-url', true);
        //$registration_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-registration-url', true);
        $cta_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'min_event-cta-text', true);
        $cta = !empty($cta_text) ? $cta_text : 'Register Now';

        $i++;
        if ( $i == 1 ) {
            ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="event col-sm-4">
            <a href="<?= $url ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb-events'); ?>
            </a>
            <h1><?= htmlentities($post->post_title) ?></h1>
            <div >
                <div><?= $date_string; ?></div>
                <div><?= htmlentities($location) ?></div>
                <div><a href="<?=$url;?>" class="register-now"><?= $cta; ?></a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- <p><?= $description ?></p> -->
            <!-- <p><a href="<?=$url;?>" class="register-now"><?= $cta; ?></a></p> -->
        </div> <!-- .event -->
        <?php


        if ( $i == 3  || ($events->current_post +1) == $events->post_count) {
            ?>
            </div> <!-- <?php echo $i; ?> .row <?php echo $n; ?> -->
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            $n++;
        }

    endwhile;
endif;

ob_start();
?>

<?php
$return = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
wp_reset_postdata();
if ( $echo ) {
    echo $return;
} else {
    return $return;
}
 }
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you try `var_dump(count($events->posts));` to check if there is really only one result? Did you try posts_per_page 999? Are you sure that there are more than 1 posts which match your criteria?

Comment: I tried those, it still displays only 1 post @Blackbam

Answer (score 2):

Your meta query is wrong (this mistake happens easily and I made it once myself). If you are doing 'meta_query' you have to make arrays inside arrays, each array for one meta argument. See code below:

```
$events = new WP_query(array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'min_event-start',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
        'key'     => 'min_event-start',
        'value'   => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '>',
    ))
));
```

More information on the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Thanks. I did that and still only 1 post is showing

Comment: Hmm thats strange. Try with another meta key. Try type => 'numeric' though I think its not necessary for dates. Check for actions and filters in your theme / plugins. Maybe something filters the output?

If still not working you could hack around using $wpdb in order to query the posts.